# Proxy in package.json not working when using with axios

Tags: reactjs, proxy, axios

I tried everything on the internet but my proxy just doesn't seem to work. No matter what all axios requests are always hitting the endpoint on which the client is running.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "keeper-part-3-starting",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Created with CodeSandbox, using React. A simple keeping notes app, which allows addition and deletion of notes",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^6.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.14",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "qs": "^6.9.6",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "start": "node src/server.js",
    "server": "nodemon src/server.js",
    "client": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.4"
  }
}
```

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";
import axios from "axios";
import qs from "qs";
const port = parseInt(process.env.REACT_APP_PORT) + 1 || 3001;

function App() {

  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [useEffectCall, setUseEffectCall] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api/notes")
      .then(res => {
        setNotes(res.data);
        //console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
      //console.log(useEffectCall);
  }, [useEffectCall]);

  function addNote(note) {
    const newNote = qs.stringify({
      title: note.title,
      content: note.content
    });
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    };
    axios.post(
      "/api/notes/addNote",
      newNote,
      headers
    ).then(res => {
      console.log("new note added!");
      setUseEffectCall(`add ${res.data}`);
    });
  }

  function deleteNote(id) {
    axios.delete(`/api/notes/${id}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setUseEffectCall(`delete ${id}`);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea addButtonOnClick={addNote} />
      {notes.map((note) => {
        return (
          <Note
            key={note._id}
            _id={note._id}
            title={note.title}
            content={note.content}
            deleteButtonOnClick={deleteNote}
          />
        );
      })}

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
//const Promise = require('bluebird');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) + 1 || 3001;
const router = express.Router();
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

  
// module.exports = function(app) {
//     app.use(
//       proxy("/api/notes", { target: "http://localhost:3001" })
//     );
//   };

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../build")));
    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,  "../build"));
      });
}


const notes = require('./api/notes');
app.use('./api/notes', notes);
//app.use(express.static("../public"))
//app.use("/", router);


app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

api/notes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const router = express.Router();

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://admin-shashwat:Test123@cluster0.586se.mongodb.net/notesDB", {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true}); //mongodb://localhost:27017/

const notesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String
});

const Note = mongoose.model("Note", notesSchema);

router.get("/", function(req, res){
        Note.find()
        .then(notes => res.json(notes))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
        console.log("hello");
    });

router.post("/addNote", function(req, res){
        const newNote = new Note({
            title: req.body.title,
            content: req.body.content
        });
        newNote.save()
            .then(() => res.send(newNote._id))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: "+ err));
    });

router.delete("/:noteId", (req,res) => {
        Note.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.noteId)
        .then(() => res.send("Deleted successfully"))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: "+ err));
    });
    
module.exports = router;
```

I tried deleting node_modules and package-json and then doing npm install, didn't work.

I tried creating setupProxy.js file and using http-proxy-middleware like this

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/api/notes', 
    { target: 'http://localhost:3001/' }
));
};
```

didn't work.

The only time it works is when I don't use proxy and instead provide the entire URL to axios, but I want to use proxy, since Im deploying it on heroku.